# SPI readings always high (1) when connected via bi-directional level shifter

Tags: adc, spi, esp8266, level-shifting, nodemcu

I am trying to read two gas sensors (MQ4 for methane and MQ7 for carbon monoxide) with my NodeMCU ESP8266. Both sensors require 5v (for the heaters) and have 4 pins (GND, VCC, DO, AO). Digital outputs are HIGH when a threshold is exceeded (adjustable on the breakout board).
In order to read analog outputs, I am using MCP3008 10 bit ADC, which works with higher accuracy at 5V. ESP8266 is however 3.3V.

I am using 8-channel bi-directional level shifter to communicate with MCP3008.
MCP3008 and sensors are connected to Vin and GND on NodeMCU ESP8266 board, which provides 5V.

Level shifter is also connected to 5V on HV side and 3.3V on LV side.
Level shifter works fine for digital outputs of sensors.
But when it comes to SPI between MCP3008 and NodeMCU ESP8266, I always read high values (1023).
When I get rid of the level shifter and power MCP3008 with 3.3V with a potentiometer, I can read values between 0-1023.
Also the sensors output analog values between 0-5V (tested with lighter gas and multimeter). So there must be a problem between level shifter and SPI communication.

On the software side, I tried to do the communication manually, with SPI.h and 
Adafruit_MCP3008.h libraries.
They work fine, when I remove level shifter and operate MCP3008 with 3.3V.

I was wondering, what the problem might be? I don't have an oscillator and it is my first "real" electronics project. Excuse my lack of jargon...
Thanks!

EDIT: I use this level shifter: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01FRQUQCS/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1
[image: Schematic]
[image: Level shifter]

Comment: Which level shifter are you using (I do not see it mentioned in your question)? Schematics would be nice to add too.

Comment: @Martin I added the information.

Comment: Do you have access to a scope you can probe it with?  If not, what do you read if you stop driving the chip select pin, and instead experiment with grounding the MISO line on each of the low voltage and high voltage sides?

Comment: How fast are you trying to run the SPI?  Have you tried slowing it down to see if the level translation is messing up the SPI timing?  Can you look at the waveforms during the SPI transfers with an oscilloscope?

Comment: Incidentally, while not part of your main experiment "power MCP3008 with 3.3V with a potentiometer" is an extremely unsound idea.  You can't use a potentiometer to regulate voltage for an active circuit with a power draw that varies by phase of operation.  You would need a high bandwidth control loop to continuously adjust the potentiometer to account for the changes in load - an assembly traditional sold under the name "linear voltage regulator".

Comment: @crj11 I tried to slow it down by setting SPISetting to 1, 1000000, 10000000. I also tried to add delayMicroseconds(1) after each digitalWrite() call to SPI pins.

Comment: 500 kHz (if I interpret correctly, that you are bit-banging SPI with 1us delay after each change) can be still bit too high for such level translator (100 pF and 10 kOhm has characteristic time just 1 us and your line has probably much higher capacitance). Try to go down to, say, 10 kHz or even less for test purposes. Still not too good idea to use such translator circuit for any faster data transfer.

Comment: @Martin I tried with 100 and 1000 μsec, and 100msec and it didn't helped. I am not actually concerned about the speed. I can do slower but I am not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't completely get what you are suggesting. Do you mean if I read the MISO line, while it is connected to ground? or if there is a resistor between MISO line and ground? Or do I read the line, while I don't drive the clock and CS pins?

Comment: If you ground the MISO line, then your SPI attempts should no longer read all high.  Try that on the far side of the voltage translator as well as the near.  Preferably do not drive the chip select when you are doing this experiment, so that you don't have a bus contention between the actual peripheral and your test short-to-ground.

Comment: I would suspect some timing issue anyway. Hard to analyze without scope, but double check your code versus waveforms in MCP3008 datasheet. Are all timings correct even if you assume each rising edge (on any signal) to take "random" time up to ~10 us? Maybe too slow rise time itself could cause problem, but I do not see any limit in the datasheet.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ok, I grounded LV3 (low voltage side of MISO), which reads 0. But when I ground HV3 (high voltage side it reads 1 (high)). Which is weird to me. When I plug the D6 MISO wire on LV side from LV3 during operation it is still high for a while. It gets low (0) when I insert it in GND.

Comment: @Martin I may have access to one at work. But I have found similar reports on this page: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009 ESP8266 is faster (80MHz). I will try to slow it down once again.

Comment: "But when I ground HV3 (high voltage side it reads 1 (high)). Which is weird to me." You need to figure out why and fix that.  If the level translator won't pass a permanent low from a ground jumper, it's not going to pass data either.

Comment: @ChrisStratton There is this question which seems to be a very similar issue: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/298981/level-shifter-default-high-problem?rq=1 There the conclusion is that it is suitable for SPI but I need to connect to non-high output. I didn't really get the solution.

Comment: That link is irrelevant and the "conclusion" there all but meaningless.  You have a fundamental problem that your circuit does not work properly even when the input is produced by human hands.  Until you fix that, there's little point in theorizing about anything else.

Comment: Decrease your pull up resistor values on the level shifter to 1k.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been long abandoned by the asker with critical detail missing.  No resolution appears possible.

Comment: I am sorry for abandoning this question. I can't remember what the problem was (I was only able to work on it shortly over long period of time). I remember now that my breadboard had loose contact with some of the pins. I can't remember though if this was related to this problem. Another problem I had later on was my solder flux, which was conducting unless cleaned very well (in IPA with ultrasonic cleaner).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the asker has stated they no longer have access to the system and cannot remember the nature of the problem

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is caused by the edges of the outgoing clock getting messed up by the level translator.  That translator is really designed for I2C signals, which have very slow edges.  SPI signals are designed to be driven high and low, while I2C signals are driven low and  pulled high by resistors.  You might be able to get it working by changing the HV side pullups to a lower value.

TI makes [the SN74GTL2003](http://www.ti.com/product/SN74GTL2003/datasheet/abstract#SCDS3051837)  which is  similar to the NMOS level translator you are using, but is designed to work at high speed.  The main difference is that the TI part has several matched MOSFETs and uses one of them that's not used as an I/O to set the gate voltage for all of the MOSFETs.  This sets the maximum voltage that is passed through.  Pull up resistors on the high side then set the maximum voltage on the high side.  This is all explained in the TI documentation.